# In which city in Europe would a first-time cross-dresser face the lowest risk of harassment?

Tags: europe, safety, local-customs, events

What would be the safest, most friendly city to go out as cross-dresser? Specifically, in Europe?

It is not easy to come out, and I have been considering it for a while. I want to try it somewhere, where my sight would not attract violent reaction, or *too* many comments (some are okay ;)

What city (or neighborhood) in any European country would be best for it? Also, should I consider any specific time of year or event?

What I already consider:

- Vienna, specifically during Vienna Pride week
- Camden, London, specifically on Halloween

These events would possibly be good occasion, as lots of people already dress themselves up.

BTW, I would not travel in a group, as I have not come out to my friends and family yet. I am thinking of going out in another city as it gives me some degree of anonymity.

Comment: First thought, Amsterdam, city center, but do research which clubs as not all might be as welcoming. (And I do not go out in Amsterdam.)

Comment: Most German cities I would expect some looks and that's it. Of course, every village has an idiot, but if you don't meet him, you'll be fine.

Comment: Gay village in Manchester?

Comment: Brighton (Southern England) is another likely one

Comment: I'd love to be able to answer **everywhere**, but alas...

Comment: Another place with a very liberal "anything goes" reputation is the Christiania district of Copenhagen (Denmark). Bit of a crazy place in other ways though, by all accounts.

Comment: @CMaster I've heard mixed stories from my trans friends about Manchester's gay village. Parts of it are very cis-male-gay and can be pretty hostile to the LBT letters of the acronym.

Comment: @RichardGadsden useful information. I've seen plenty of cross-dressers out and about there - but note that cross dressing and trans are frequently not at all the same thing.

Comment: England should be a good choice imho, as long as it's a city and not a village.

Comment: Helsinki. Harrassing somebody would require the Finns to talk which they wouldn’t do ;)

Answer (score 6):

My first guess was the Nollendorfplatz area in Berlin but the second is [Le Marais in Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Marais#LGBT_culture):

> Le Marais has "an emphasis on 'commercialism, gay pride and coming-out of the closet'"

And if you would consider North America, I live very close to [Davie Village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davie_Village) in Vancouver. I do not think there's any gender identity or expression that would draw even a passing look here.